# What is VBS UCASE function doing to Japanese?

Tags: vbscript, character-encoding, asp-classic, uppercase

In order to avoid case conflicts comparing strings on an ASP classic site, some inherited code converts all strings with `UCASE()` first.  This seems to work well across languages ... except Japanese.  Here's a simple example on a Japanese string.  I've provided the UrlEncoded values to make it clear how little is changing behind the scenes:

```
Server.UrlEncode("戦艦帝国") = %E6%88%A6%E8%89%A6%E5%B8%9D%E5%9B%BD 
UCASE("戦艦帝国") = ƈ�ȉ�Ÿ�ś�
Server.UrlEncode(UCASE("戦艦帝国")) = %C6%88%A6%C8%89%A6%C5%B8%9D%C5%9B%BD
```

So is UCASE doing anything sensible with this Japanese string?  Or is its behavior buggy, undefined, or known to be incompatible with Japanese?

(LCASE leaves the sample string alone.  But now I'm wary of switching all comparisons to LCASE because I don't know if it bungles other non-western languages that *do* work with UCASE....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1systdcy(v=vs.84).aspx

> Only lowercase letters are converted to uppercase; all uppercase letters and non-letter characters remain unchanged.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case

> Most Western languages (particularly those with writing systems based on the Latin, Cyrillic, Greek, Coptic, and Armenian alphabets) use letter cases in their written form as an aid to clarity. Scripts using two separate cases are also called bicameral scripts. Many other writing systems make no distinction between majuscules and minuscules – a system called unicameral script or unicase.

"lowercase or uppercase letters" does not apply in Chinese-Japanese-Korean languages, hence, the output of UCase() should remain unchanged.

Comment: *Should*, but does not.  Therefore is this simply an open bug in the VBS UCASE function?

Comment: the actual value of your string literals in your ASP page depends on the encoding of your source code file. it will be different if you save your file as UTF-8 instead of UNICODE.

Comment: It will follow the Unicode standard. Read the Unicode standard to see what should happen. VBScript uses C's `ToUpper`. *If c is a wide character for which iswlower is true and there is a corresponding wide character for which iswupper is true, towupper returns the corresponding wide character; otherwise, towupper returns c unchanged.*

Comment: @feetwet I tested and get the same result as yours. `txt = "戦艦帝国" : Response.Write Server.UrlEncode(txt) & "<br>" & Server.UrlEncode(UCase(txt)) & "<br>"`

Comment: looks like internally, the string is first encoded and stored as UTF8, the first character is \xE6 [æ] which is converted to \xC6 [Æ] by UCase()/toUpperCase()/ToUpper()

Comment: this will work correctly: `Response.CodePage=65001 : txt = ChrW(25126) & ChrW(33382) & ChrW(24093) & ChrW(22269)` it ensures the string to be stored in the correct wide-characters internally

Comment: hence, it is not an issue with UCase(), but it is how the string get stored in the memory before UCase() process it